# SSLError, Bad Key Share

Tags: ssl

I get this error all this week, and I doen't know how this fix, It's error, drop from Python + Cherrypy, (webhook telegram bot, module telebot), and one bot on webhook work correctly, second bot doesn't work correctly and I don't understand this, both bots have same structure and difference it's bot TOKEN, I hope on help. Thanks for Attention:

│ssl.SSLError: [SSL: BAD_KEY_SHARE] bad key share (_ssl.c:1123)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, it helped to allow the package to work with certificates:

1. `pip install pyopenssl`
2. change Cherrypy config

   ```py
       cherrypy.config.update({
       'server.socket_host': 'zzz',
       'server.socket_port': 'zzz',
       'server.ssl_module': 'pyopenssl', #not use'builtin'
       'server.ssl_certificate': 'zzz',
       'server.ssl_private_key': 'zzz'
   })
   ```